# Create logical GUI components group using windows builder

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am writing a GUI app in WindowsBuilder eclipse java and have some questions:

1. I have a check button that if it's checked some controls are enabled. Is there an elgant way to allow all of them by one command? I mean that I dont want to enable them one by one, just enable them at once - is it possible to define a logical group that will allow me to do it?
2. Is there any common design pattern to write Java GUI applications?

I am new in Java, so will appriciate any guidance in these queastion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in function to check/uncheck them all with one command.

The "easiest" way that comes to mind is to store them all in a `List` and create a function that iterates over that list and checks/unchecks everything.

```
private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

// ADD YOUR BUTTONS

private void setSelectionForButtons(boolean enabled)
{
    for(Button button : buttons)
        button.setSelection(enabled);
}
```

Then you can check/uncheck them all by calling:

```
setSelectionForButtons(true);
```

or

```
setSelectionForButtons(false);
```

---

As for the "design patterns": There is an excellent tutorial for writing SWT applications [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SWT/article.html).